# How can I assign a variable the promise results of an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

I'm trying to learn how to use axios from this site: [Asynchronous Javascript using Async - Await](https://scotch.io/tutorials/asynchronous-javascript-using-async-await)

```
async function getGamerDescription() {
    const text = await axios.get(`/api/gamer/${id}/gamerBio`);
    return text.data;
}

console.log("bio: ", getGamerDescription());
```

gives me:

```
bio:  Promise {<pending>}
```

If I put the console.log INSIDE the getGamerDescription() function, then it writes out the bio text that I need.

But I need to assign the bio text to a variable so I can display it on my website.

Is there a way to do that?

I found some other SO questions:

[Axios returns promise pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740335/axios-returns-promise-pending)

[My call async/await returns a Promise {} in my actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055935/my-call-async-await-returns-a-promise-pending-in-my-actions/54055958)

But they didn't help.

I just want to be able to get the value so I can assign it to a variable.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function

Answer (score 1):

An async function automatically becomes a promise, so in this case `getGamerDescription` is actually a promise, so you have to use `await` when logging it, but await can only be called inside an async function, so try this:

```
async function getGamerDescription() {
    const text = await axios.get(`/api/gamer/${id}/gamerBio`);
    return text.data;
}

(async () => console.log("bio: ", await getGamerDescription()))();
```

Notice I wrapped the `console.log` inside an async IIFE and used await inside the `console.log`, this is because I'm treating the async function `getGamerDescription` as a promise. If you wanted to assign it to a variable you need to do that using `await` inside another `async` function

Comment: but how would  assign it to a variable? Like if I need to display the bio on my website, that means my whole component would need to be `async`?

Comment: Inside another async function `const something = await getGamerDescription()`